# Approaches to fast visualization of huge amount of data

Tags: .net, performance, algorithm, compression, plot

I am looking for some approaches to compress a big (and dynamically growing) amount of data for visualization in a graph view.

Say I have a binary file consisting of timestamp-value pairs. This file is growing in realtime and can easily exceed several gigabytes.

Now there are multiple views displaying this data as graph/plot. Since in most cases there is far more data than pixels on our x-axis, we need to somehow compress this data to the desired resolution. Each view may require a different resolution depending on its size on the screen. Also zooming in and out will cause quick changes of that resolution.

The current algorithm divides the data into sections of equal length and calculates the minimum and maximum value. Now for each pixel on our x-axis, we draw a vertical line from min to max value. This way we can be sure not to miss outliers. (Which is a requirement)

Each time a new resolution is required, we have to choose another section length and go through the whole file, which is way to slow.

A solution would be to create some kind of caching layer allowing us to make (constant time) calls for data of different resolutions. Unfortunately I do not know how to implement such a cache in a way that still shows us outliers.

Do you have any hints or know literature showing approaches to this kind of problem?

The environment is Microsoft .net but that shouldn't make a difference since this is about general ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My approach would be to store the data in several files, like this:

- append the {timestamp, value} to FILE[0].
- for i = 0 ... MAX_REASONABLE:

  - if FILE[i]'s sample count modulo ZOOM is nonzero, exit.
  - get last ZOOM samples from FILE[i].
  - compress them into a single sample (e.g. average timestamps? Get minimum?)
    and average sample data.
  - if FILE[i+1] does not exist, create it.
  - write the newly created sample to FILE[i+1]

The total amount of data converges to SIZE * (1/(1-(1/ZOOM))) - you need 100% extra space if ZOOM=2, and only 33% if ZOOM=4, and so on.

When visualizing, you quickly choose which is the closest level to show. Say that you need to visualize 800 pixels from a range containing 600.000 samples, with ZOOM=2; then the logarithm of 600.000/800 divided by the logarithm of ZOOM gives 9.55, which means that you need to access zoom level 9.

That file is zoomed ZOOM^9 = 512 times, i.e. you will read 600.000/512 = 1171 samples and resample the 1171 x H image to 800 pixel width.

Total write costs will increase by at most 300% on average; total storage requirements will increase by at most 100%; to generate an image your cost becomes more or less constant, depending on the width of the screen image you generate.

I have worked on such systems for map rendering, and it is possible to show a rectangular area from a terapixel map with real time panning and zooming (except for network throughput and latency, that is: there, we played with JPEG quality).

Comment: Thank you. The answer was very helpful. We finally agreed to implement it that way.